# Excel Function Wizardry: Calculating average required to achieve a goal value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a set of data for 7 days which gets updated with a value at the end of each day. This is what the data might look like by day 3.

Day1 11

Day2 25

Day3 18

Day4 N1

Day5 N2

Day6 N3

Day7 N4

I want to calculate what the average of the remaining "unknown" days needs to be such that the average of ALL 7 days >= 20. The 'unknown avg' would recalculate at the end of each day as we get a new 'actual' value in.

Comment: This is really an arithmetic question rather than an Excel question.  But for the 7-day average to be at least 20, the total must be at least 140.  So 140 minus the sum of known days is the minimum sum of the unknown days.  Divide that by the count of unknown days to get their minimum average.

Comment: Thank you. You and Gary's Student got me to where I need to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fixer1234's solution.  In **C1** through **C5** enter:

```
20                    Desired average (at least 20)
=7*C1                 Desired sum
=SUM(B1:B7)           current sum
=C2-C3                deficit
=C4/COUNTBLANK(B1:B7) required average
```

[image]

So the average of **B4** through **B7** must be at least 21.5.

Comment: Thank you, I was overthinking it and COUNTBLANK was the key part I was missing here. Works beautifully.

Comment: @JStandard  You are quite welcome.